# How do I return custom content with an error response in IIS 7?

Tags: iis, iis-7, web-services, json

My API returns JSON content with some errors, such as 500 (Bad Request). Under IIS 6, this worked fine. In IIS 7, once I turn off detailed error messages it simply returns the text "Bad Request". How can I keep the contents of my response intact?

Comment: Have you found an answer to that question? I'm interested in it. Thank you.

Comment: @Jean-Francois I must have, because I don't have this problem anymore. I'm surprised I didn't come back here add an answer. I'll take a look and see if I can remember what I did.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Error Responses to 'Detailed errors' in the Error Pages setting of IIS7. Open that, then click on 'Edit Feature Settings', you'll find it there.